# Use $\sin(x)/x \geq 2/\pi$ to deduce whether $\sum \sin(1/n)$ diverges

Tags: sequences-and-series

If I know that $\sin(x)/x \geq 2/\pi$ for $x$ in $[0, \pi/2]$, how can I deduce that $\sum_1^\infty \sin(1/n)$ diverges?  I'm not seeing any connection between the two.  By inspection, it looks like the series converges to 1, but I don't even need to know the limit.  I just need to argue that it converges.

My professor has been comparing series and sequences.  I have used the harmonic series to show others diverge.  I've used Euler's series of inverse squares to show others converge, so there's probably a comparison here that can do this one as well.

Comment: Actually $\sin(x)/x \geq 2/\pi$ for $0 < x \le \pi/2$, and you can use that to show that $\sum_1^\infty \sin(1/n)$ *diverges.*

Comment: Thanks, @MartinR.  I had just noticed the inequality mistake, but I did think it the series converges.

Comment: @MartinR, I would say it doesn't because I can't use these powerful theorems yet.  I thought Julio Puerta's was much better, but I also don't have this fundamental limit yet.

Comment: This answer https://math.stackexchange.com/a/2530893/42969 in that Q&A uses exactly your estimate.

Comment: I agree.  The second answer does.  Thanks very much.  (Should I delete the question?  I wonder.)